# Run Laravel on Apache local

Tags: apache, laravel

I want to run laravel on apache that apache provide in folder

```
/var/www/
```

1. I have installed apache2 and laravel
2. I created a project with laravel
3. it's runs nice with

   ```
   php artisan serve
   ```

How do I use it? I copied all laravel project to /var/www, but when I open

```
lcoalhost/project_name/
```

it's just show the directory root..

Can anyone help me?

I just want to create website that I consume by myself from my android via ap-hotspot, so I can open my ubuntu ip and open my project

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't just copy the folder and expect it to run.

Depending on how you installed it you can use composer (within the directory where you copied the files to) if you installed [composer](https://getcomposer.org/download/) at all.

1. composer install

   ```
   composer install
   ```
2. composer update

   ```
   composer update
   ```
3. start development server

   ```
   php artisan serve
   ```

Comment: i want to access it from others computer through ad-hoc, i need run the project from apache

Comment: try php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0

Answer (score 0):

You should configure the document root in Apache as:

```
/var/www/project_name/public
```

Laravel's public folder has the index.php file that is used to create/run the application you've written.

On an install of Ubuntu that I have, the document root was initially set to `/var/www/html` and this was set in the file:

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

If you open up this file using `nano`, `vim` or another appropriate editor.

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

Then you'll need to change the following line to your required root directory:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
```

becomes

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/project_name/public
```

Also open this file;

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Then locate this entry;

```
<Directory /var/www/html/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Again, change `/var/www/html` to your preferred directory and save.

After your changes are saved restart Apache.

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: how to configure that?